# PythonShell.run returns null in results nodejs

Tags: python, node.js

I am trying to run python script in nodejs via PythonShell. But I am getting null in results. I don't know whether python script is returning null value or there is problem in nodejs code.

Nodejs Code

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');
////options for python-shell
PyShellOptions={
mode: 'JSON',
pythonOptions: ['-u'],
scriptPath: 'F:/University/Final Year/FYP/From Shafeeq/ECG-Diagnosis (Python)',//python scripts folder
args: [signal_file,sample_rate,user.meta.age,user.meta.gender,user.meta.height,user.meta.weight]
};

    PythonShell.run('main.py', PyShellOptions, function (err, results) {
        console.log(err);
        if (err) {
             console.log(err.message)
        }
        // results is an array consisting of messages collected during execution
        console.log('results: %j', results);
}
```

Python Code

```
print(json_content)
```